# ZF2 upload file not working

Tags: php, zend-framework

i need your help. I tried to create form upload using Zend Framework 2 and follow the instruction from [here](https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/zend-framework-2-creating-upload-form-file-validation/), the return allways `echo "failed";` and the file not want to switch to a predetermined place.

Here's my code :

```
$nonFile = $request->getPost()->toArray();
$File    = $this->params()->fromFiles('fileupload');
$data    = array_merge_recursive(
    $this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray(),           
    $this->getRequest()->getFiles()->toArray()
);
if(!empty($data['fileupload']['name'])){                
    $size = new Size(array('min'=>2000000));
    $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http(); 
    $adapter->setValidators(array($size), $File['name']);
    if($adapter->isValid()){
        $adapter->setDestination('./helpdesk');
        if ($adapter->receive($File['name'])) {
            echo "success ";
        }else{
            echo "failed";
        }
    }else{
        echo "no upload file";
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me ? is there something wrong with my code ?

Comment: You should write full path for Destination like starting from C/:..

Comment: What do you mean by failed. It isn't clear. Are there errors? Revise the question with the errors. Ensure error reporting is enabled, see http://www.phptherightway.com/#error_reporting.

Comment: @GerardRoche there's no error message, but the result is always go to `echo "failed";`

Comment: @HardikPatel ya, i also tried to use `__DIR__` in `$adapter->setDestination` but it's still always displaying part of `echo "failed";`